# How to make network of twitter with networkx (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, networkx

I'm a beginner for programing. 
I'm struggling to make network relation of my twitter follows and followers with networkx. Here is my code I have done :

```
from pylab import *
from networkx import *
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key = my_consumer_key,
                  consumer_secret = my_consumer_secret, 
                  access_token_key = my_access_token_key, 
                  access_token_secret = my_access_token_secret, 
                  input_encoding = "UTF-8")


friends = api.GetFriends()

G = networkx.Graph()

for friend in friends:
    G.add_edge(myname,friend.screen_name)


for friend in friends:
    for user in api.GetFriends(friend.id):
        if user in friends:
            G.add_edge(friend.screen_name,user.screen_name)


pos = spring_layout(G)


draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size = 100, node_color = 'w')
draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width = 1)
draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size = 12, font_family = 'sans-
serif', font_color = 'r')

xticks([])
yticks([])
savefig("egonetwork.png") 
show()
```

I was emulating some example code, however I got result

```
>>> module 'twitter' has no attribute 'Api'
```

I can't find out answer and also try to use tweepy instead of twitter, however almost same result. How should I edit ?? It would be greatly appreciated if you could explain the details.

Comment: Try to use another package: `sudo pip3 uninstall twitter` and then `sudo pip3 install python-twitter.`